# How can I remove duplicate values ​from my json in React

Tags: json, reactjs, reduce

I am developing an application with React and I have a problem. I have made a fetch from a json and the values are repeated. I want only each value to appear once.

I hope that it only returns once each of the elements of "Padre": "CRM", "Permisos" and "Telefonia". The same for "Hijo".

I've tried changing ".concat" to ".reduce" because I've read that it can be done like this, but it does not work. I have seen examples but none of them works on "this.state" so I do not know how to do it.

Can you help me with the correct way to do it?

This is a part of my json file

```
[
   {
      "Id":"114",
      "Padre":"CRM",
      "Hijo":"Argumentarios"
   },
   {
      "Id":"115",
      "Padre":"CRM",
      "Hijo":"Argumentarios"
   },
   {
      "Id":"116",
      "Padre":"CRM",
      "Hijo":"Argumentarios"
   },
   {
      "Id":"44",
      "Padre":"Permisos",
      "Hijo":"root"
   },
   {
      "Id":"45",
      "Padre":"Permisos",
      "Hijo":"root"
   },
   {
      "Id":"46",
      "Padre":"Permisos",
      "Hijo":"root"
   },
   {
      "Id":"47",
      "Padre":"Permisos",
      "Hijo":"root"
   },
   {
      "Id":"50",
      "Padre":"Telefonia",
      "Hijo":"Audio"
   },
   {
      "Id":"51",
      "Padre":"Telefonia",
      "Hijo":"Audio"
   },
   {
      "Id":"52",
      "Padre":"Telefonia",
      "Hijo":"Configuracion"
   },
   {
      "Id":"70",
      "Padre":"Telefonia",
      "Hijo":"Rutas"
   }
]
```

For confidential reasons I can not show the actual file. 
In my next code I change the fetch for a fake json url

**I Edit my code with @Avanthika and @blaz code.** Currently the code works but shows only the first value it finds of "Father" and "Son". I need to show only once each of the different values ​​of "Father" and "Son". Example result:
Father:
     CRM
     PERMISOS
Son:
     ARGUMENTARIOS
     ROOT

Currenly, with my new code i see only: CRM (Padre) and Argumentarios (Son). The rest of the elements are not shown.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Nav extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            menuSubmenu:[]
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        fetch('http://FAKE.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(menuSubmenu =>{

            menuSubmenu.forEach(datos => {
                let data = {
                    menu:datos.Padre,
                    submenu:datos.Hijo,
                    id:datos.Id
                }

                //console.log( data )
                //console.log (data.menu);
                this.setState({ 
                    menuSubmenu:this.state.menuSubmenu.concat([data])
                }) 
            })
        })
    }
    render() {
        const array = [...this.state.menuSubmenu];
        const distinctValues = array.filter(
            ({ Padre, Hijo }, index) => {
              return array.findIndex(item => item.Padre === Padre && item.Hijo === Hijo) === index;
          });
          //console.log(this.state.menuSubmenu);
          //console.log(distinctValues);

        if (distinctValues.length > 0) {
          return(
            <div>
              {distinctValues.map(datos => <Navegacion key={datos.id} menu={datos.menu} submenu={datos.submenu} />)}
            </div>
          );
        }
        return (<p>Cargando usuarios...</p>);
      }
}

class Navegacion extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
                     <ul className="list">
                        <li className="list__item">{this.props.menu}
                            <ul className="list">
                                <li className="list__item">
                                    <a href="#">{this.props.submenu}</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default Nav;
```

This image is the result of my json.[My json result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYKBO.png)

I hope you can help me with the "reduce" function.
¡Thanks a lot!

Comment: when you say "values are repeated" you mean duplicate ids? or duplicate by every key? in other words what keys are the criteria for duplication?

Comment: So you only want to remove objects that are repeated?

Comment: Hi. I want to say that for example the value "CRM" appears 15 times when I would like only 1 to appear. "All the values ​​of" Padre" and" Hijo"are repeated many times in my json and I want only to return the value once. And I want remove objects repeated.

Comment: `menuSubmenu.forEach` in `componentWillMount`, I think that's creating lots of duplicates for you.

Comment: Why are you doing concat inside a foreach loop? I guess that's why duplicates are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Original solution from Avanthika](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55853130/2404452) doesn't work because in your data, some item might possibly have `Padre` value containing dash character ("-"). Use a character that will never appear in `Padre` value as separator instead and you will be good.

My solution:

Use `Array.prototype.filter`

```
const distinctValues = this.state.menuSubmenu.filter(
  ({ Padre, Hijo }, index) => {
    return this.state.menuSubmenu.findIndex(item => item.Padre === Padre && item.Hijo === Hijo) === index;
});
```

With `Array.prototype.reduce` it will look more bulky:

```
const distinctValues = this.state.menuSubmenu.reduce(
  (array, item) => {
    if (array.findIndex(i => i.Padre === item.Padre && i.Hijo === item.Hijo) === -1) {
      array.push(item);
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: With your solution I have: An error in line 17 in the "foreach", an error in line 26 with my "this.setState" and an error in line 43 "Can not read property 'length' of undefined".

Comment: @CasandraLópezReal For error in line, you better provide screenshot since we cannot know which line it is. But judging from this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0syDm.png - if the line number is the same then you should check the API response instead, and it is not related to the question you asked.

Comment: Sorry @blaz for the last comment. I edit my original post with version 2.0 (screenshot errors)

Comment: See my update. Please change `indexOf` to `findIndex`. Also console.log `this.state.menuSubmenu` and `distinctValues` and give us the values in console if the issue still occurs.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I edit my original code with your changes. The code works but i 
I need the render to show each different element only once

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use lodash and function uniqBy https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy

```
_.uniqBy(menuSubmenu, function (e) {
  return e.Padre;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use new Set to unique your array list by Padre and Hijo.

```js
const array = [{"Id":"114","Padre":"CRM","Hijo":"Argumentarios"},
{"Id":"115","Padre":"CRM","Hijo":"Argumentarios"},
{"Id":"116","Padre":"CRM","Hijo":"Argumentarios"},
{"Id":"44","Padre":"Permisos","Hijo":"root"},
{"Id":"45","Padre":"Permisos","Hijo":"root"},
{"Id":"46","Padre":"Permisos","Hijo":"root"},
{"Id":"47","Padre":"Permisos","Hijo":"root"},
{"Id":"50","Padre":"Telefonia","Hijo":"Audio"},
{"Id":"51","Padre":"Telefonia","Hijo":"Audio"},
{"Id":"52","Padre":"Telefonia","Hijo":"Configuracion"},
{"Id":"70","Padre":"Telefonia","Hijo":"Rutas"}];

const distinctValues = Array.from(new Set(array.map(elem => `${elem.Padre}-${elem.Hijo}`))).map(distinctVal => {
  const [ Padre, Hijo ] = distinctVal.split("-");
  return ({
    Id: array.find(elem => elem.Padre === Padre && elem.Hijo === Hijo).Id,
    Padre,
    Hijo
  });
});
console.log(distinctValues);
```

2. Or you can go for lodash as mentioned to extract uniq values. You have to use uniqBy.

```js
const array = [{"Id":"114","Padre":"CRM","Hijo":"Argumentarios"},
    {"Id":"115","Padre":"CRM","Hijo":"Argumentarios"},
    {"Id":"116","Padre":"CRM","Hijo":"Argumentarios"},
    {"Id":"44","Padre":"Permisos","Hijo":"root"},
    {"Id":"45","Padre":"Permisos","Hijo":"root"},
    {"Id":"46","Padre":"Permisos","Hijo":"root"},
    {"Id":"47","Padre":"Permisos","Hijo":"root"},
    {"Id":"50","Padre":"Telefonia","Hijo":"Audio"},
    {"Id":"51","Padre":"Telefonia","Hijo":"Audio"},
   {"Id":"52","Padre":"Telefonia","Hijo":"Configuracion"},
    {"Id":"70","Padre":"Telefonia","Hijo":"Rutas"}];

const distintValues = _.uniqBy(array, elem => [elem.Padre, elem.Padre].join());

console.log(distintValues);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You need to fix the solution this way:

```
render() {
  const array = [...this.state.menuSubmenu];
  // Put the solution you like here.
  // const distinctValues = the solution you like
  if (distinctValues.length > 0) {
    return(
      <div>
        {distinctValues.map(datos => <Navegacion key={datos.id} menu={datos.menu} submenu={datos.submenu} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (<p>Cargando usuarios...</p>);
}
```

Comment: The first option seems the best but I do not understand how to join "const array" with my external json. The information of my json is dynamic and is changing.

Comment: Your array in this case will be `this.state.menuSubmenu`

Comment: ```const array = [...this.state.menuSubmenu];``` You need to do this in render() where you've done the console.log.

Comment: I've edited my code, if it works, please accept and upvote the answer :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not get it to work. I'm learning and I still do not know enough. I have edited my original post with the new code, in case you can review it. Sorry for the inconvenience